# Open SQLite3 file as string c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am tring to open a SQLite format 3 file as a string in C#

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\Test\Downloads\hello.sql";

            using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open),
                                                   Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
            {
                int pos = 0;
                int length = (int)b.BaseStream.Length;
                while (pos < length)
                {
                    int v = b.ReadInt32();
                    textBox1.Text += (v);

                    pos += sizeof(int);
                }
            }
```

This is the code I have got so far, but when I try open it, it freezes and wont let you do anything, as if its on a constant loop trying to open it.

If you are still confused on what I am trying to do. If you where to right click on the file and open it with notepad or notepad++ you can see the file contents(String) and thats what I want to be displayed in the String or textbox in the program.

P.S Im not wanting to open it in a SQLite format, I want to open it as text

Comment: It is not clear what is that sql file. It contains some SQL statement in clear text like "SELECT/INSERT" or it is the binary file where SQLite stores its data? I mean, when you open it with Notepad do you see garbage characters or it is a plain text file

Comment: Most of it is garbage characters but the bits that I want out of it are in plain text that I can see when I open it with notepad.

Comment: did you debug that ? it is really difficult to provide a solution without the file with the real data

Comment: When I debug it, it just freezes and never crashes so i cant get any infomation from that.

Comment: If your able to right click and open it with notepad, i dont see why it wont work when i try open it in my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to do this, but this method is efficient:

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\Test\Downloads\hello.sql";
textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filename, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
```

or if you want to see the file contents as byte values, you can use:

```
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
textBox1.Text = BitConverter.ToString(buffer);
```

Edit:

This code works with winforms textboxes. Instead of just checking for 0x00 I check for all control characters using .NET's char.IsControl function and replace them.

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\Test\Downloads\hello.sql";

byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
char[] chars = enc.GetChars(buffer);

for (int n = 0; n < chars.Length; n++)
{
    if (char.IsControl(chars[n])) chars[n] = '.';
}

textBox1.Text = new string(chars);
```

Comment: textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filename, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)); outputs "SQLite format 3"

and 
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
textBox1.Text = BitConverter.ToString(buffer);
outputs nothing as it frezes.

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to test this on my own machine now, but what about File.ReadAllBytes combined with Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString? If that doesn't work, try replacing all 0 bytes with 32 (space) before calling GetString. How big is your file?

Comment: the file is 1.02MB, and I will just try your other idea now

Comment: The combining Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString and File.ReadAllBytes didnt work and Im not to sure how to get the byte replacing to work.